# GradientPaint rotation

Tags: rotation, gradient, affinetransform

I have a shape that rotates around one end of itself coloured in by a gradient paint.

```
GradientPaint turretShade = new GradientPaint(Math.round(x+((1.0/2.0)*le)),Math.round(y+((1.0/2.0)*le)),green,
                                                Math.round(x+((1.0/2.0)*le)), Math.round(y+((1.0/2.0)*le)+(1.0/10.0)*le)
                                                ,new Color(0x1A3C12));
g2d.setPaint(turretShade);


Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,-(0.5/10.0)*le,(3.0/4.0)*le,(1.0/10.0)*le);
g.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000);
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.translate(x+((1.0/2.0)*le),y+((1.0/2.0)*le)+(0.5/10.0)*le);
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(turretang));
Shape rotateRect = transform.createTransformedShape(rect);
g2d.fill(rotateRect);
transform.translate(0,0);
```

The problem i have is that when i rotate the shape it move out of the set gradient. Any idea's on how to rotate the gradient with the shape?